# UBUNTU 20.04 LTS: Missing 'lbconfig' and a 'libc-bin' c library

Tags: dependencies

A frustrating problem occurred when I sudo apt-get update --> then: sudo apt-get upgrade on UBUNTU 20.04.

I had recently gone through a successful upgrade of PYTHON3.8 to PYTHON3.10 - BUT I do not know if this was responsible for missing ldconfig files and a missing sbin library in usr/locale/.

I checked the 3 root sbin locations: /sbin, usr/locale/sbin, and usr/sbin.  /sbin and usr/sbin had the c program utilities in them - but was missing 'ldconfig' utility.  AND usr/locale/sbin directory was completely missing.

Here is the messages Linux gives me when I tried to fix broken links:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/633 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3802 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I had previously downloaded - but did not install - libc-bin - which was a .deb archive called `libc-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb` - and had successfully cp'd it over to usr/locale/sbin.  When I tried to install and checked - the archive name had changed to 'sbin' in usr/locale/ but had not extracted.

Has anyone run into this issue and been able to navigate to a solution that does not require scrapping the UBUNTU and doing a complete reinstall?

One final note:  I am running UBUNTU in a Microsoft Windows 10 machine under WSL.  I am only using the command line to configure UBUNTU 20.04 LTS.

ALSO --

The error msgs also mention a missing PERL5 script -- Encoding.pm - but I have not looked into it.

Thank you for your genius in helping me get out of this swamp of problems.

Comment: To be clear you have changed the default version of Python that came with the OS?

Comment: Yes.  I did this in order to add ROCm drivers to my AMD graphics card in order to use AI processes under AUTOMATIC1111 gui - that were designed to use NVIDIA cuda.  The ROCm drivers work with AMDs HIP to translate and requires python3.10.

Comment: **I'm guessing**, but replacing Python is prone to create problems, as it is an deeply buried dependency for many things - apt / apt-get for starters. In the process you also may have a created a situation with a replacement "new" libc which isn't "known" to some of the OS software. This kind of tinkering requires good knowledge of the OS internals.

Comment: Thank You for your kind input.  Would creating a Docker "shell" or environment around all this extra stuff that is needed for this prompt/image AI Graphical User Interface and AMD drivers and interpreters etc. be the cleanest way to keep from mucking up Ubuntu's innards?